# How to echo "$x_$y" in Bash script?

Tags: string, bash, shell

It is very interesting that if you intend to display `0_1` with Bash using the code

```
x=0
y=1
echo "$x_$y"
```

then it will only display

```
1
```

I tried `echo "$x\_$y"` and it doesn't work.

How can I echo the form `$x_$y`? I'm going to use it on a file name string.

Comment: Enable syntax colouring in vim. You will immediately spot simple errors like that.

Comment: `echo $x\_$y` would work; enclosing the same in double quotes would protect the backslash.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Because variable names are allowed to have underscores in them, the command:

```
echo "$x_$y"
```

is trying to echo `${x_}` (which is probably empty in your case) followed by `${y}`. The reason for this is because parameter expansion is a greedy operation - it will take as many legal characters as possible after the `$` to form a variable name.

The relevant part of the `bash` manpage states:

> The `$` character introduces parameter expansion, command substitution, or arithmetic expansion.
>
> The parameter name or symbol to be expanded may be enclosed in braces, which are optional but **serve to protect the variable to be expanded from characters immediately following it which could be interpreted as part of the name.**
>
> When braces are used, the matching ending brace is the first `}` not escaped by a backslash or within a quoted string, and not within an embedded arithmetic expansion, command substitution, or parameter expansion.

Hence, the solution is to ensure that the `_` is *not* treated as part of the first variable, which can be done with:

```
echo "${x}_${y}"
```

I tend to do *all* my bash variables like this, even standalone ones like:

```
echo "${x}"
```

since it's more explicit, and I've been bitten so many times in the past :-)

Comment: Using a good text editor with syntax highlighting helps immersively to detect such glitches without cluttering all the code with explicit `${x}` notation.

Answer (score 12):

This way:

```
$ echo "${x}_${y}"
0_1
```

Answer (score 8):

wrap it in curly braces:

`echo "${x}_${y}"`

Comment: ANy one knows why bash behaving so?. `echo "$x.$y"`. With `dot` it is working.

Comment: because variables can have underscores in them but not dots -- with underscores it thinks you have variables called `$x_` and `$y`. but with dots it won't get confused

Comment: variable names can't have dots, values can have anything

Answer (score 5):

Just to buck the trend, you can also do this:

```
echo $x'_'$y
```

You can have quoted and unquoted parts next to each other with no space between.  And since `'` isn't a legal character for a variable name, bash will substitute only `$x`.  :)

Comment: @tomriddle_1234: In what way does it not work?  If you enclose the argument to echo in double quotes, it won't work, but the command was written without double quotes for a reason.

Comment: And, for another way of dealing with it: `x=0; y=1; z=_; echo "$x$z$y";`