# Variable Expansion when using variable within filename

Tags: bash

When using Bash I want to `WGET` multiple files from a server so I write a script with a For-loop that increments a counter to match the numbering of the files.

But I want to include the title of the file AND the number in which order the file appears (the "ID" of the file). So the the file has a URI of "example.com/files/hello_world.txt", with the ID of 42 and the title is "Hello World" when `WGET` it, the downloaded file should have the name "42_Hello_World.txt".

I tried the following code:

```
#! /bin/bash

# Init
index=42
title="Hello World"

# Replace blanks with underscore
title=${title/ /_}

# Concat fileName
fileName="$index_$title.txt"
echo $fileName
```

but the output is just "Hello_World.txt". When I change the order of $title and $index the output is "42.txt"

Can someone explain to me why this happens and how to solve it?

tl;dr
When using two or more variables in bash when evaluating a string only the last variable is "expanded". The first one is ignored. WHY???

Comment: Your tl;dr misidentifies the problem; both variables *are* expanded, but the first expansion isn't using the name you think it is.

Answer (score 2):

`_` is a valid character for an identifier, so `$index_$title.txt` is interpreted as the concatenation of two parameter expansions, `$index_` and `$title`. To explicitly delimit the parameter name, use the full `${...}` form:

```
fileName=${index}_$title.txt
```

The braces are not necessary for `$title`, because the following `.` cannot be interpreted as part of a parameter name (though the braces are certainly permitted: `${index}_${title}.txt`).

Since `index_` is not defined, `$index_` expands to the empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The explanation is the the `_` character is a valid character in a variable name, so that your expressions are expanding the (undefined) variables `$index_` and `$title_` as empty strings. (The `.` is not a valid name character, so it terminates the 2nd name automatically.) Do this instead:

```
$ fileName="${index}_$title.txt"
$ echo $fileName
42_Hello_World.txt
$ echo "${title}_$index.txt"
Hello_World_42.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. This change should provide you your expected results. It is simple your variable `"$index_$title.txt"` is considered as you are concatenating 2 variables (`index_` and `title`) so its better to quote `_` like --> `"_"` and tell shell that it is a string.

```
index="42"
str="Hello World"
# Replace blanks with underscore
title=${str/ /_}
# Concat fileName
fileName=$index"_"$title".txt"
echo $fileName
```

In this nice url, you could see the last example of VALID variables(`_` is there in the list):

https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Rules_for_Naming_variable_name

Answer (score 0):

The `_` in the filename is not helping. `_` is a valid variable character, and bash thinks that you want a variable called `$index_` followed by `$title`, which isn't what you want. You can either:

1. Change the underscore character to an invalid variable name
2. Change to `filename=$title"_"$index".txt"` or
3. put brackets around `$index`

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**: You already have an answer here! [How to echo "$x_$y" in Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390955/how-to-echo-x-y-in-bash-script)