# find command returns different output on terminal vs bash script

Tags: bash, terminal, find

I'm dealing with a rather peculiar issue. I want to catch all file names in a directory that contain a range of numbers. The directory has the following files

```
run_1_500ns.root
run_2_500ns.root
run_3_500ns.root
run_4_500ns.root
run_5_500ns.root
...
run_55000_500ns.root
```

For instance I want to get the files `run_600_500ns.root` and `run_601_500ns.root` and feed them in the `hadd` command (that's a command from the ROOT/cern data analysis software).

If I run the following command on a terminal I get the filename that I'm looking for.

```
$ filename=`find . -name "*_600_*.root" | sed 's#.*/##'`
$ echo filename
run_600_500ns.root
```

However, if I run the following script, I get all files in the directory.
This script used to work on `redHat 6` but at the moment I'm using `Ubuntu 18.04`. Not sure if that's the issue, but it's the only (big) change in my setup. Any idea on what might be the issue?

```
#!/bin/bash
# A script to add root files using hadd command
# NOT idiot proof

#variables
CURRENT_DIR=$(pwd)


echo

if [ "$#" -eq 4 ]; then
    
    #input arguments
    OUT_ROOT=$(readlink -f $1)
    FILES_DIR=$(readlink -f $2)
    FIRST_RUN=$3
    LAST_RUN=$4
    
    echo
    echo "Output file : $OUT_ROOT"
    echo "Input files : $FILES_DIR"
    echo
    
    cd $FILES_DIR
    
    #source_root_files="*"`seq -s "*.root *" $FIRST_RUN $LAST_RUN`"*.root"
    source_root_files=""    
    filename=""
    
    for i in $(seq $FIRST_RUN $LAST_RUN); do
        filename=$(find . -name "*_$i_*.root" | sed 's#.*/##')
        source_root_files="$source_root_files $filename"
    done

    
    echo "Merging root files"
    hadd -f6 $OUT_ROOT $source_root_files
    
    cd $CURRENT_DIR
else
    echo "Provide the correct number of arguments"
    echo "Usage   : radd.sh <output root file> <input root file directory> <first run> <last run>"
fi
```

Running the script as `sh -x script.sh 2> log.log` gives me the following

```
+ pwd
+ CURRENT_DIR=current_directory
+ echo
+ [ 4 -eq 4 ]
+ readlink -f test.root
+ OUT_ROOT=current_directory/test.root
+ readlink -f .
+ FILES_DIR=current_directory
+ FIRST_RUN=600
+ LAST_RUN=601
+ echo
+ echo Output file : current_directory/test.root
+ echo Input files : current_directory
+ echo
+ cd current_directory
+ source_root_files=
+ filename=
+ seq 600 601
+ find . -name *_*.root
+ sed s#.*/##
+ filename=S0Test_51686_500ns_CW_0ns_CBT_0ns_DEBT.root
```

Comment: Your script doesn't pass https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Add `set -x` at the beginning to get an execution trace and see what's going wrong.

Comment: @GillesQuenot Yes, I saw. It's weird... It evens complains about `cd`

Comment: @GordonDavisson I did that and it seems the filename isn't parsed correctly and I don't know why. See updated question

Comment: @Thanos: personally, I will not help here, there's too much to say. If you update your code to pass shellcheck, you will have more help. The most important is the need to quote "$variables". 
Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

  > "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and _every_ expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See

Comment: <http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes>    
<http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments>    
<http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words>

Comment: @GillesQuenot Hard to pass spellcheck. Thanks for your time ans study material though!

Comment: Start by quoting your variables.

Comment: shellcheck shows the problem clearly: in `"*_$i_*.root"`, it's treating `$i_` as the variable reference, not just `$i`. To disambiguate it, use `"*_${i}_*.root"`. I have no idea how this could've worked on RH6, since the way it's parsing it should be the same under any Bourne-family shell. I'd also recommend fixing everything else shellcheck points out, except for double-quoting `$source_root_files` in the `hadd` command -- in that case, your script *depends on* word splitting. As for why `cd` should be checked, see [this sad story](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378942).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks for your help!  If I `echo $i` I get exactly what I want so I'm confused about having to use `${i}`

Comment: @Thanos Variable name parsing after `$` is greedy -- if characters *could* be part of the variable name, then it assumes they *are* part of the variable name, and `_` *can* be part of a variable name. See ['How to echo "$x_$y" in Bash script?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390955/how-to-echo-x-y-in-bash-script) and Giles' answer to ["$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/var-vs-var-and-to-quote-or-not-to-quote).